# How to resolve a "DuplicateColumn" error when running Django migrations?

Tags: python, django

I'm encountering an issue while running migrations in my Django project. Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn: column "order_address" of relation "orders_order" already exists
```

This error seems to be related to the migrations process. I have checked my migration files and ensured that I'm not explicitly adding the "order_address" column multiple times. However, the error persists.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you perhaps modify the database manually? Or perhaps deleted and faked some migrations? Or perhaps you set the `db_column` argument on fields in your model? Please provide the appropriate debugging information on **how** you ended up in this situation.

Comment: I am just start working on a new project. I didn't modified anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre].